# Unable to install Intel HAXM on azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, android-studio, azure-virtual-machine, haxm

I'm trying to run an android virtual device on azure virtual machine that has support for nested virtualization

I'm getting this error:

**Unable to install Intel HAXM

VT-X is disabled in BIOS

Enable VT-X in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation on your computer)**

I tried installing Intel HXAM for android studio running inside azure vm and getting the error above and I can't access BIOS in azure vm to enable it.

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: VT-X is Virtualization (needed to run the emulator smoothly). But you do not have permission or access to change the BIOS of cloud hardware. You can contact with Azure technical team for this problem.